# Small read size by Windows SMB client

Tags: windows, samba, server-message-block, wireshark

I am setting up a Linux server for high resolution online video editing. When I access the SMB share from a Windows 11 client, Wireshark analysis shows that the SMB Read requests are always a maximum of 256K in size. For efficiency I would like the disk accesses on the server to be larger.

In Linux when we mount a SMB share we can specify options like rsize. Are there similar options we can set in Windows clients when we are mapping a drive. Ideally I would like to set this to 1MB.

Note that this is not a restriction from the server side. When the negotiation happens the server advertises a Max Read Size of 8MB. Also the client's TCP Window size is much bigger.